# neural network estimation of compositions distribution

Tags: neural-networks, compositional-data

To use feed forward neural network to predict compositional distribution, e.g.fractions of nutritions, vitamin 10%, protein 35%, water 35%, salt 20%, for each composition sample, sum composition percentages of all elements equal to 1.

My question is, for estimating such compositional distribution, what activation function should I use at output layer? It looks similar to regression problem, but sums of each dimension of a single composition data must equal to one, which similar to logistic regression or softmax. Should I use softmax? or linear as activation function at output layer?

Comment: Rather than what activation function should you use, I wonder if adjusting a Softmax output using a MSE loss is feasible, or if you would run with potentially vanishing gradients. Indeed, a very interesting question. I posted one very similar